# malloc: *** error for object 0x1746ea3fe: Invalid pointer

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading

> malloc: *** error for object 0x1746ea3fe: Invalid pointer dequeued
>   from free list *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

How to solve the error? Error on thread and running on iPad with iOS 10.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An app is 1 process with N threads. If one thread crashes, the whole app crashes.

In Xcode show the *Breakpoint Navigator* (on the left). Then click the + at the far-bottom-left and select *Symbolic Breakpoint...* Finally in the *Symbol* field fill in `malloc_error_break` and you're done; run the app again.

Comment: I can't debug my application. Can you please provide how to handle this issue at runtime during application running time.